# Rails select_tag - how to send ajax request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to send an AJAX request once an option is selected (changed) from the `select_tag` in Rails 3.1. Can we use `:remote=>true` or `:onchange => remote_function()` or is there some other way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should definitely do this with jQuery (with an unobtrusive approach to keep things as clean as possible). On your .js file you should have something like this...

```
$('#select_tag_id').change(function(){
  $ajax({
    url: "remote_action_in_your_controller",
    type: "GET",
    data: {select_tag_value: $('#select_tag_id option:selected').text()},
  })
});
```

this is as simple as it should be if you just want to call a remote action on your controller (notice I passed the value of the selected option since you probably want that value to do something with it). If you need to do something after the ajax call is executed use the `succes` option. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to run an action which does some computation with the data sent via ajax and then render a partial view on the same page.. How can that be done here ?

Comment: should be `$.ajax`

Answer (score 1):

You must to do it with JQuery. Something like this, when the document is ready, :

```
$('#your_select_tag').change(function() {
  $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
           url: "http://your_url/",  
           success : function(text) {
              alert('success')
           }
  });
});
```

See the doc : http://api.jquery.com/change/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: I want to run an action which does some computation with the data sent via ajax and then render a partial view on the same page.. How can that be done here ?

Comment: You could do your computation in the change function. After that, you could create a app/views/controllers/action.js.erb and you could do what you want in your file. There is an example here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300498/how-do-i-include-html-in-a-js-rails-response.

Comment: Sorry, I think I might not have been clear. I want to give the option selected (say, 'foo') from the select_tag to my controller action, which would find out the details for 'foo' in a database, store them in a map, and then the same controller action will render a partial to display the details from the map. How can this be implemented ?

Comment: So, you can pass argument in the url like this : `url: "http://your_url/my_controller/my_action?param1=var_1&param2=var2"`. After that, you should have your params in your controller. After, you should create app/views/controllers/action.js.erb like in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

`remote: true` adds `data-remote="true"` to the html element. Just add this as a CSS class in the `select_tag` options.

```
<%= select '', '',  @coaches, {}, { data: {remote: true } } %>
```

Please note the `data: { remote: true }` is used because `"data-remote"` is not Ruby friendly.